# vb.net form and container sizing with "Change the size of all items" altered

Tags: vb.net, forms, screen

I have an application that works great at the default 100%, however if the user has changed the screen to 125% or something else the runtime sizing of a group container and the form size itself fail. What am I missing? Based on conditions a group box is re-located on the form and the form resizes. I confirmed this by re-setting my system to 125% and adjusting the runtime repositioning of the controls and form to match, it worked then.

Comment: Have a look at this microsoft page about dpi in apps .. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7trainingcourse_win7highdpinative_topic1

Comment: Check out this [question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101791/make-vb-net-application-dpi-aware).

Comment: That page uses VS2008, I am using VS2013 and do not see the referenced "HighDPIApp.sln " on my system nor in the Project menu is there an option for "HandsOnLabProperties", am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done, and it is working so far:

Added App.manifest to the project with the following code added:

```
  <asmv1:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <dpiAware>true/PM</dpiAware>
  </asmv1:windowsSettings>
```

Added the following sub to my startup form:

```
Private Sub GetScreenDPI()

    Dim dspGraphics As Graphics

    dspGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics 'Graphics for user's display

    g_int_ScreenDPI = dspGraphics.DpiY

    Select Case g_int_ScreenDPI

        Case 96 'Smaller 100%

            g_dbl_screenDPI = 1

        Case 120 'Medium 125%

            g_dbl_screenDPI = 1.25

        Case 150 'Larger 150%

            g_dbl_screenDPI = 1.5

        Case Else 'Custom

            g_dbl_screenDPI = g_int_ScreenDPI / 100

    End Select

    dspGraphics.Dispose()

End Sub
```

And where I need to scale the controls or form positions:

Me.Height = CInt(550 * g_dbl_screenDPI)