# Report viewer on another PC in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, report

I am using microsoft report RDLC, in my pc that I am using for programming the report viwer work just fine I have many reports in A4 paper size, but in anther pc the paper size appears with extra white space .attched pictuers for both.

#### my PC:

[image: my PC]

#### other PC:

[image: other PC]

Comment: I think it's going to be a relationship between the actual size of the report (in Report Server), and the other user's printer settings.  I couldn't find a similar Stack Overflow question, but see if this one points you in the right direction https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/044cef87-5944-47f8-8d3d-cd9bcfb1c4da/reportviewer-extra-space?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: In addition, I would also just ensure that the setting on the report itself are Consume White Space = true

Comment: consumecontainerwhitespace is true , tried the link apove but i got all the sizes right , thanks  Craig

Comment: i found the problem its the DPI scaling in the other PC is 150% when i change it to 100% it works , now i am trying to disaple dpi scaling for this specific form

Comment: Either of these point you in the right direction?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101791/make-vb-net-application-dpi-aware  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411240/report-viewer-scaling-issue-with-system-dpi-change